# Android Navigation Drawer template not working

Tags: android

I was trying to create a new project using New Navigation Drawer Project and it did not work, when I try to click one of the navigation drawer option nothing happen.

I didn't change anything, I created a new project and ran it.

```
   class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar)

        binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
        val navView: NavigationView = binding.navView
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow
            ), drawerLayout
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        //navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

    }


    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        Log.e("e","clicked")
        return true

    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

This is my main activity, I added  override fun onNavigationItemSelected
to debug what happen, it did not get executed.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the `NavigationView` is not brought to front. To fix it, you can go to `activity_main.xml` and move `NavigationView` below others.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_main"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: It is working, thank you very much. But why does it have to be below others ?

Comment: In Android, views below in xml will be rendered on top of other view. So in your case, the ```app_bar_main``` is displayed on top of ```NavigationView```. So when you click on the drawer, actually you are clicking on ```app_bar_main```, not the ```NavigationView```